# Redirect to specific page when view expires on JSF + Primefaces

Tags: jsf, primefaces, custom-error-pages

I have an error page configured in my `web.xml` like this:

```
<error-page>
    <exception-type>javax.faces.application.ViewExpiredException</exception-type>
    <location>/index.xhtml</location>
</error-page>
```

If the page in the browser in the path like: `${context.path}/something.xhtml` and the view expires on that page it redirects correctly to `${context.path}/index.xhtml`, but if my context path is different for e.g.: `${context.path}/secure/something.xhtml` and if the view expires on this page then it tries to redirect `${context.path}/secure/index.xhtml` and of course it fails because there is no `index.xhtml` page under the path ../secure/. Why is this happening? I thought that if have location like this: `<location>/index.xhtml</location>` in my `web.xml` it will always redirect to the root context path. How can I make JSF to redirect always to root context path `/index.xhtml`?

Comment: It should indeed work that way. Which servletcontainer impl/version are you using? Do you happen to have a custom `Filter` or `ExceptionHandler` to handle JSF (ajax) exceptions? Are you sending synchronous or asynchronous (ajax) requests? Namely, PrimeFaces uses by default ajax requests and those kind of requests doesn't make use of `<error-page>` facility at all; perhaps you're manually handling them yourself elsewhere.

Comment: @BalusC, thanks to guide me, but i have resolve few path related issue with same technique where we provide full path from main dir and surprisely i have resolved all

Comment: @BalusC, Servlet container is Tomcat 7.0.37, I have a filter which just set character encoding to UTF-8 and that's it, I don't have any exception handlers. In terms of primefaces requests yes there are some with ajax but they are all synchronous and I am not handling them anywhere else.